# If i add this function on the code, NSTimer stops, why?

Tags: ios, loops, swift

There are 2 `Array`s. First one contains `String`s that i want to show on `UILabel`. Second one contains their waiting durations on `UILabel`.

```
let items = ["stone","spoon","brush","ball","car"]
let durations = [3,4,1,3,2]
```

And two `variable`s for specifying which one is on the go.

```
var currentItem = 0
var currentDuration = 0
```

This one is the timer system:

```
var timer = NSTimer()
var seconds = 0

    func addSeconds () {seconds++}
    func setup () {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "addSeconds", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

Finally, that's the loop. Answer of: Which `Array` item stays how many seconds on the `UILabel` question.

```
func flow () {
        while seconds <= durations[currentDuration] {
            myScreen.text = items[currentItem]
            if seconds == durations[currentDuration]{
                seconds == 0
                currentItem++
                currentDuration++
            }
        }
```

Label and Button:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var myScreen: UILabel!
    @IBAction func startButton(sender: UIButton) {
        setup()
        }
}
```

If i change this:

```
func addSeconds () {seconds++}
```

To that:

```
func addSeconds () {seconds++ ; flow () }
```

For setting the loop, nothing happens. Even NSTimer, it stops at 1st second.

Comment: You should use NSTimeInterval to calculate elapsed time

Comment: But if i don't include `flow ()` function and say `println (seconds)` inside `addSeconds()` function, there're no any problems, it says seconds correctly.

Comment: That's what you think.

Comment: Don't say `var timer = NSTimer()`. Just say `var timer: NSTimer!`. Your version creates an unused object.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus okay i've corrected that but can you please explain the difference? I'm not so experienced.

Comment: @robmayoff thank you very much for that suggestion, i've corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your flow method has a while loop that never exits and blocks the main thread, so the timer can never fire.

Don't use a while loop. Us the method triggered by the timer to update the UI.

So:

```
func addSeconds () {
    seconds++

    myScreen.text = items[currentItem]

    if seconds == durations[currentDuration] {
        seconds == 0
        currentItem++
        currentDuration++
    }
}
```